# Understanding Joomla default login

Tags: php, joomla, authentication

I'm fairly new to Joomla and Php in general. I need to understand how does Joomla perform login operation (via php code). The following is the php snippet that performs the operation:

```
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&task=user.login'); ?>" method="post">

        <fieldset>
            <?php foreach ($this->form->getFieldset('credentials') as $field): ?>
                <?php if (!$field->hidden): ?>
                    <div class="login-fields"><?php echo $field->label; ?>
                    <?php echo $field->input; ?></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php if (JPluginHelper::isEnabled('system', 'remember')) : ?>
            <div class="login-fields">
                <label id="remember-lbl" for="remember"><?php echo JText::_('JGLOBAL_REMEMBER_ME') ?></label>
                <input id="remember" type="checkbox" name="remember" class="inputbox" value="yes"  alt="<?php echo JText::_('JGLOBAL_REMEMBER_ME') ?>" />
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <button type="submit" class="button"><?php echo JText::_('JLOGIN'); ?></button>
            <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo base64_encode($this->params->get('login_redirect_url', $this->form->getValue('return'))); ?>" />
            <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

To my understanding, the first line perform POST request to post username and password to the server. In addition, a session token, should be retrieved upon successful validation. However, I could not figure out where exactly are the username and the password (that are inserted by the user and supposed to be sent via POST request) in this line. Or, where are they retrieved from? In addition, where is the response content (session Token) is stored?

My objective is to mimic the request using JavaScript so that I can perform login using external mobile App. In other words, I need to write the same logic in JavaScript so I can login to the website from mobile App.

Answer (score 1):

The fields are retrieved from login.xml file from the following path \components\com_users\models\forms. getFieldset('credentials') will get field details of the fieldset in the name "credentials" `<fieldset name="credentials"` in the above mentioned file.And you can use foreach to display the field. You can refer this [link](https://docs.joomla.org/API16:JForm/getFieldset) for more info.

Comment: Thanks, And what does this part do `echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&task=user.login` exactly? I'm looking for where the credentials values are sent to the server. In addition, where the session Token is stored ?

Comment: task=user.login. Which means it is taking you to controller file "user" to the function "login". \components\com_users\controllers\user.php and find the function login. Token will be stored as session.Joomla has its own method to check the form token. You can find the following code `JSession::checkToken('post') or jexit(JText::_('JInvalid_Token'));` in the above controller file, which will validate the token.To know more about the token refer [link](https://docs.joomla.org/API17:JRequest::checkToken).You can find the function checktoken definition in \libraries\joomla\session\session.php file

Comment: I checked the function login in user.php, it is a little bit confusing for me. My understanding, it that username and password will be collected from fieldset name="credentials". And they should be sent via POST request and validated at the server, if correct, a sessionToken will be sent back. However, this function does not show where these credentials are sent. No URL is appearing whatsoever. I deeply appreciate if you can help me to understand this.